# android RtpSocket stream

Tags: android, rtp

I am trying to implement Rtpsockets like in sipdroid.
http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/sipua/ui/VideoCamera.java

sipdroid is a huge project and I can't really find a good place to start.
Can anyone help me find a simpler project or give me some source code to start with?

Thank You,
Amitay Molko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up editing this project https://github.com/spex66/RTSP-Camera-for-Android/
Fully implementing the rtsp client to work with remote servers.
You can find my code here http://www.4shared.com/rar/cm2e1ZML/RtspCamera.html